# "no main manifest attribute" in Spring Boot Application using Spark-Streaming when packaged with maven-shade-plugin

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, spark-streaming-kafka

Here is my pom.xml :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.adobe.tahoe</groupId>
    <artifactId>KafkaSparkStreamingDemo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>KafkaSparkStreamingDemo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <gson.version>2.8.5</gson.version>
        <scala.version>2.10.4</scala.version>
        <scala.binary.version>2.10</scala.binary.version>
        <spark.version>1.6.0-cdh5.16.1</spark.version>
    </properties>


    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>cloudera</id>
            <url>https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>

        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>-->


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-core_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-sql_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>


        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka_2.11</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka_2.10</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0.0</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!--Dstream Kafka Integration Dependencies -->


        <!--<dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>-->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming-kafka_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${spark.version}</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
            <artifactId>spark-streaming_2.12</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.5</version>
        </dependency>




    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <!--<version>3.1.0</version>-->
                <!--<dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>-->
                <configuration>
                    <keepDependenciesWithProvidedScope>false</keepDependenciesWithProvidedScope>
                    <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                    <filters>
                        <filter>
                            <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </filter>
                    </filters>
                    <transformers>
                        <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                            <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                        </transformer>
                        <transformer
                                implementation="org.springframework.boot.maven.PropertiesMergingResourceTransformer">
                            <resource>META-INF/spring.factories</resource>
                        </transformer>
                        <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                            <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                        </transformer>
                        <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                        <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                            <mainClass>com.adobe.tahoe.KafkaSparkStreamingDemo.KafkaSparkStreamingDemoApplication</mainClass>

                        </transformer>
                    </transformers>

                    <relocations combine.children="append">
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>com.google.</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>shaded.com.google.</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                    </relocations>

                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Application details : This is spark-streaming application consuming data from Kafka based on spring-boot for dependency injection/IoC container.

I'm packaging it using maven-shade-plugin with  tag specified in transformer , however when I try to

```
mvn clean package -DskipTests
```

and then run it using `java -jar JAR_NAME.jar`

I'm getting

```
no main manifest attribute,
```

What might be the reason ?

I would like to clarify that I don't want to use **spring-boot-maven-plugin** because of this issue : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/2895 which is still open .

Comment: First you should use the spring-boot-maven-plugin cause the issue is related to creating WAR files ...which you are not doing..you should read issue carefully ...apart from that have you tried to use spring-boot-maven-plugin and failed? I have my doubts...

Comment: @khmarbaise yes I've tried using spring-boot-maven-plugin and got the same error i.e. zip64 binary archives not supported

Comment: You really have more than 65535 files? I think there is something wrong..how large in the resulting jar/war file? have you configured to create zip64 binaries?

Comment: You really have more than 65535 files? : Don't know , should I explode the jar and count the number of files ?

have you configured to create zip64 binaries?  : No , I think it is spark which does it.

Comment: You really have more than 65535 files? : Why are you asking this ? How is it related to no main manifest attribute error ?